# About the Jenkins if else statement in a pipeline

Tags: jenkins

My Jenkins have a pipeline task name the 'if-test'.

I have a log file name the 'result.log' and it placed on this task Workspace path.

Now, I want to check this result.log file content has a word 'FAILED', then run `Jenkins pipeline stage A`.

And, if this result.log file content is not included the word 'FAILED', then run `Jenkins pipeline stage B`.

I try to use the `def aa = (sh grep -i 'failed' ./result.log)....`

But, I think it's the wrong statement.

Everyone who can help me to find the correct statement for that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer something like below, populate the details as and what required.

```
  node{
   stage ('Build'){

   if (readFile('test').contains('FAILED')) {

       echo "present"

    }

    else {
        echo "absent"
    }



    }
}
```

Comment: Hi guys,
Yes, this is I need.
It's can be resolved my case.
Thank you for helping.